# Angular img src console error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` to print all the images from desired folder, and those images are in `<a>` because I'm using [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

Here's an example of controller:

```
var ParentCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.getTimes=function(n){ // for the ng-repeat
        return new Array(n);
    }; 
};

app.controller('projectController', ['$scope','$injector', function($scope, $injector) {
    $injector.invoke(ParentCtrl, this, {$scope: $scope});

    $scope.title = 'project';
    $scope.image_url = 'img/project/';
    $scope.image_num = 14; //image count -> [0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ..., 13.jpg]
}]);
```

And the template:

```
<a href="" class="fancybox" rel="project-gallery"
    data-ng-repeat="t in getTimes(image_num) track by $index" 
    data-ng-href="{{image_url+($index)+'.jpg'}}">
        <img src="{{image_url+($index)+'.jpg'}}">
</a>
```

And this code works fine, it shows all the 14 images. However, I'm getting this error in the console:

```
GET http://localhost/projects/project-name/%7B%7Bimage_url+($index)+'.jpg'%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

How to fix that error?

Comment: check this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc
It's because browser tries to fetch the image with`src` you provided. If you use `ng-src`, angular will take care of waiting until the expression is compiled, and then append `src` to the `<img>` element.

Comment: Well, that was stupid of me, I forgot about `ng-src`. I'm still learning angular so I can "afford" to make those errors :D
Cheers :)

Comment: No probs.  It was a good question.  On hind-sight now, maybe we update the title to reflect the "src" attribute since we now have a good belief that it wasn't ng-repeat related?

Comment: Doh. Same mistake here! Forgot abiut ng-src ... I blame switching between too many languages/environments/frameworks!! x)

Answer (score 6):

In your template, please use `data-ng-src` as opposed to `src`.  Your new template will become

```
<a href="" class="fancybox" rel="project-gallery"
    data-ng-repeat="t in getTimes(image_num) track by $index" 
    data-ng-href="{{image_url+($index)+'.jpg'}}">
        <img data-ng-src="{{image_url+($index)+'.jpg'}}">
</a>
```

See

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc